# Como gravar em um arquivo números entre 0 e 10

Tags: c

Gostaria de entender como faço para gravar em um arquivo, numeros de 0 a 10, a partir deste código:

```
main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    int num[10],i; 
    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo = fopen("c:\\Ling_C\\resultado.txt","a");

    if(arquivo==NULL){
        printf("Arquivo texto.txt não pode ser aberto!\n");
        getchar();
    }
    else{
        for (i=0;i<10;i++){
            fwrite(&num[i],sizeof(int),10,arquivo);
        }
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente a barra está invertida no caminho do arquivo.

Segundo a função [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) recebe alguns parâmetros o parâmetro 
`fopen("file", **a**)` indica que irá concatenar ao final do arquivo, utilize o 
`fopen("file", **w**)` se quiser sobreescrever.

Para escrita em arquivos você pode utilizar a função [fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/), segue link com definição de algumas funções para escrita em arquivos:

[As funções fputc(), fprintf() e fputs()](http://www.cprogressivo.net/2013/11/Escrevendo-em-arquivos-As-funcoes-fputc-fprintf-fputs.html)

Veja o exemplo abaixo e em seguida seu output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *arq;
    int result;

    arq = fopen("C:/Users/inpart/Desktop/EstudoC/ArqGrav.txt", "w");  

    if (arq == NULL)
    {
     printf("Arquivo ArqGrav.txt não pode ser aberto!\n");
     return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<10;i++)
    {
      fprintf(arq,"Linha %d\n", i);                       
    }

    fclose(arq);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu esperava uma resposta com `fwrite`, nas esta certamente valeu meu +1

Comment: Eu também , mas valeu com certeza o meu +1

Answer (score 4):

A [resposta do @CaiqueRomero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/249889/64969) atacou o problema por um lado que eu considero inesperado, mas muito bom. Ele também fala das demais coisas relativas à abertura de arquivos e deixou ótimas referências de leitura.

Vim aqui falar do [`fwrite`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/).

A primeira coisa é ver a assinatura da função:

```
size_t fwrite ( const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );
```

Pronto, vamos entender o que isso quer dizer. A função diz que vai imprimir na `stream` passada `count` elementos de tamanho `size_t`apontados por `ptr`.

Se você quiser imprimir dez inteiros de um vetor `v` no arquivo `f`, você poderia fazer:

```
fwrite(v, sizeof(int), 10, f);
```

Onde:

- `v` é o vetor, portanto pode ser trabalhado como um ponteiro
- `sizeof(int)` é o tamanho da unidade do vetor; também poderia ser `sizeof(*v)` ou `sizeof(v[0])`, mas prefiro passar o tipo
- `10` é a quantidade de elementos
- `f` é o arquivo aberto para escrita

---

Algumas observações:

- `fwrite` escreve os bytes, literalmente
- `fprintf` escreve a representação textual
- cabe abrir o arquivo em modo binário ao saber que se vai usar o `fwrite`, e normalmente se abre em modo textual para `fprintf` por questões de performance

  - para abrir para leitura binária, `rb` como argumento do `fopen`; escrita é com `wb`
- se você tentar abrir de modo textual um arquivo preenchido com `fwrite`, obterá um resultado assim (créditos ao [@CaiqueRomero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/88202/caique-romero) pelo print):

[image: print do @CaiqueRomero tentando abrir um arquivo binário com um editor de texto: apenas caracteres incompreensíveis]

Comment: Cara muito boa resposta!

Comment: Bem explicativo , aumenta mais o meu conhecimento , valeu !